How to hide some portion of my file
I have a book project that loads (via \input) many subfiles; each one has a theorem-like environment called `editorial' that gives some information about status of that subfile. I would like to produce a version of the book without those editorial comments. I tried using the comment package, creating a new environment editorial that just calls the comment command:
\newenvironment*{edit}{\begin{comment}}{\end{comment}}
But it produces lots of error messages. Can someone suggest a simple method to do this? I don't want to edit all of the subfiles. Here is an example of what I was trying to do.
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    %\newtheorem*{editorial}{Editorial comment} 
    \newenvironment*{editorial}{\begin{comment}}
    {\end{comment}}
    \begin{document}
    Here's the way it usually works
    \begin{editorial} 
    Here is an editorial comment
    \end{editorial}
    Now I'd like to change the editorial environment so it just doesn't appear.
    
    I could just use the comment environment
    \begin{comment} 
    This shouldn't be here.
    \end{comment}
    and nothing appears.
    %
    \begin{editorial} 
    This shouldn't be here.
    \end{editorial}
    
    \end{document}


Without the comment package, you can redefine the editorial environment to do nothing
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{editorial}{ +b }{}{}

Better, create a switch
\newif\ifprinteditorial

that can be set with \printeditorialtrue and \printeditorialfalse and print the editorial only if required
\NewEnvironmentCopy{standardeditorial}{editorial}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{editorial}{ +b }
{%
  \ifprinteditorial
    \begin{standardeditorial}%
      #1
    \end{standardeditorial}%
  \fi%
}
{}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{editorial}{Editorial comment}

\newif\ifprinteditorial
\printeditorialtrue

\NewEnvironmentCopy{standardeditorial}{editorial}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{editorial}{ +b }
{%
  \ifprinteditorial
    \begin{standardeditorial}%
      #1
    \end{standardeditorial}%
  \fi%
}
{}

\begin{document}

Here's the way it usually works
\begin{editorial}
  Here is an editorial comment
\end{editorial}
Now I'd like to change the editorial environment so it just doesn't appear.

\printeditorialfalse

\begin{editorial}
  This shouldn't be here.
\end{editorial}
and nothing appears.

\end{document}



Great, works as stated! You just rescued me from a frustrating spiral of debugging.

The comment environment works similarly to verbatim in that it looks for an explicit \end{comment} for its ending which means that your idea of just using \newenvironment won’t work because it will be unable to find the ending.
If you look at the documentation for the comment package (texdoc comment from a command line), you’ll see that the way to define a new comment environment would be with \excludecomment{editorial} in your document preamble.¹


I will say that the documentation is not entirely clear that \excludecomment means that the contents are omitted while \includecomment means that the contents are printed while the environment has no effect.


Good point. I updated the footnote.

First, thanks for the answer. It worked with some files, but not with others. I finally traced it to this unfortunate (IMO) behavior of the the comment environment: it doesn't work if there's a space before \begin{comment}. See the answers in this post Comment package not working.
